# Christian Identity - what about the racists?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

So there is a [christian-identity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-identity) tag, which appears to be used to tag questions about what identifies people as Christians, but I've recently discovered the [Christian Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Identity) Movement, where "Christian Identity" refers to a wide variety of loosely affiliated believers and churches with a white supremacist theology. I've just asked a [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34851/biblical-basis-or-rational-for-christian-identity-movement) about Christian Identity, and tagged it with [christian-identity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-identity), but I'm think this might cause some confusion down the road? Christian Identity is also known as *Identity Christianity*, should we use this to tag the racist Christian identity and create a wiki post for [christian-identity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-identity) that specifies people should use the *Identity-Christianity* tag when asking about the movement? What should be done?

Comment: To keep it clear I'd recommend using a tag like christian-identity-movement or christian-identity-ideology.

Comment: The existing tag is pretty bad. It should probably be deleted or renamed to something better (what I don't know.)

Comment: I split out a new [tag:identity-christianity] for this purpose, but I think that might be better off with a rename along the lines of one of @curiousdannii's suggestions. At least it's separate for now and we can find a name. Also the old [tag:christian-identity] tag might need a rename and a cleanup!

Answer (score 8):

This isn't really a suggestion for action, but a survey of the current situation.

A quick glance at the [christian-identity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-identity) questions suggests to me that the questions fall into three general categories:

- Questions where the tag could simply be removed without any damage to the question. Examples:

  - [Why didn't God remove the rainbow?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/24920/20)
  - https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/26789/20
  - [Do self-identified Christian fundamentalists have their own geographical communities?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/25346/20)
  - [Christian Toleration](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/20103/20)
  - [What are the good Bahasa / Malay / Indonesian words to refer to the Christian God?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/20087/20)
  - [What properties does Christianity attribute to God](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/20083/20)
- The question could be re-tagged as [heresy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heresy). Examples:

  - [Has the Catholic Church ever declared any group that identified itself Christian as not Christian?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33281/20)
  - [What is the basis that many mainstream Christian groups justify labeling groups like the Mormons and Jehovah Witnesses as Non Christians?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/24217/20)
- The question is, in some sense, actually about the identity of Christians, and probably needs a tag. But many of these are, or should be, closed as well. Examples:

  - [What is the Biblical definition of what makes one a Christian?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/24193/20)

Comment: [The last question you link](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/14786) has a weird history. That particular user was *very* difficult (typical muslim user who tries to convince us Jesus is not God). He went through a phase where he tried to get us to allow Islam oriented questions on the main site. That question was a part of that feeble attempt, claiming that we should consider muslims Christians. So yeah, it should be closed. [Caleb apparently weighed that option then, but decided not to do that.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8430079#8430079)

Comment: I already vtc'd on it, presumably back in March of 2013.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest [christian-identification](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-identification) for questions regarding how some groups identify and define Christianity.

I suggest [christian-identity-movement](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-identity-movement) for questions regarding that theology/ideology.

I suggest [identity-christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity-christianity) as a synonym for [christian-identity-movement](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-identity-movement).

I approved your recent edits to the tag wikis and excerpts because they were a step in the right direction, but they need work too.

Comment: See an aspect of the continuing discussion at https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6551/tag-synonym-request-identity-christianity-and-christian-identity-movement?noredirect=1#comment15909_6551