# Tag synonym request: identity-christianity and christian-identity-movement

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

This is a request to make the [identity-christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity-christianity) and [christian-identity-movement](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-identity-movement) tags synonyms.  The [identity-christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity-christianity) tag has been around longer and has more questions attached to it.  The [christian-identity-movement](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-identity-movement) has a wiki edit pending that's more comprehensive than what the other tag has.

Comment: identity-christianity has already been garbage collected. No need for a synonym, no one is going to type that in themselves.

Comment: @curiousdannii, when I wrote my question yesterday identify-christianity had 15 questions attached to it while C-I-M had only two.  How has it already been collected?

Comment: That's the [christian-identity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-identity) tag, not identity-christianity. I think christian-identity should be broken up [as recommended by Flimzy](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4179/6071).

Comment: Ah!  Well, the garbage collection was useful if only to avoid that very confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I would just nuke [identity-christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity-christianity) and use [christian-identity-movement](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-identity-movement). The latter will auto-complete when people start typing the former anyway, so a synonym really doesn't serve a purpose.

Comment: I'm content with this, but I've been cleaning up tags that would have auto-completed but that fact was ignored by the OP who ploughed ahead and typed in what they wanted anyway.  I regret that it (and everything else) is not a perfect solution.